# Swiftui Multi Picker change selection with min max

Tags: swiftui, max, min, picker

Hi I have a Multi picker with a minimum and maximum and i want to react if the user put the minimus over the maximum, i want to set the selection of the minimum to the maximum position so the user can't go with the minimum over the maximum. But i don't know how to change the selection of the picker during the session.

```
 struct MultiPicker: View  {

     typealias Label = String
     typealias Entry = String

     let data: [ (Label, [Entry]) ]
    @Binding var selection: [Entry]

     var body: some View {
         GeometryReader { geometry in
             HStack {
                 ForEach(0..<self.data.count) { column in
                     Picker(self.data[column].0, selection: self.$selection[column]) {
                         ForEach(0..<self.data[column].1.count) { row in
                             Text(verbatim: self.data[column].1[row])
                             .tag(self.data[column].1[row])
                         }
                     }
                     .pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
                     .frame(width: geometry.size.width / CGFloat(self.data.count), height: geometry.size.height)
                     .clipped()
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }


 struct MultiPickerView: View {

     @State var data: [(String, [String])] = [
         ("Min", Array(1...30).map { "\($0)" }),
         ("Max", Array(2...60).map { "\($0)" })
     ]
    @State var selection: [String] = [3, 10].map { "\($0)" }
        

     var body: some View {
         VStack(alignment: .center) {
             Text(verbatim: "Selection: \(selection)")
                
                    
            HStack {
                Text(data[0].0)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                Text(data[1].0)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            }
             MultiPicker(data: data, selection: $selection).frame(height: 300)
           
         }
     }

 }
```

can some one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it with:

```
 MultiPicker(data: data, selection: $selection).frame(height: 300)
 .onReceive([self.selection].publisher.first()) { _ in
                            self.correctMinMaxDays()
                        }

private func correctMinMaxDays() {
        withAnimation {
            if Int(selection[0])! > Int(selection[1])! {
                selection[0] = selection[1]
            }
        }
    }
```